# How to print after a while loop

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have Python 3.8(32-bit) installed, and I am using Atom to write my attempts and then copy-pasting them into the Python terminal.

The following code is copied directly from the very beginning of an introductory Python course I am taking "for fun":

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
  print(n)
  n=n-1
print('Blastoff!')
```

The code works in every sandbox I can find, and the last line works on its own in my terminal. But when I copy it to my terminal, I get an invalid syntax error that points to the word `print`. I can fix this and get the desired output by changing my code to:

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
  print(n)
  n=n-1
else:
    print('Blastoff!')
```

But I have three issues with this:

1. Why does my original code not work, as it is copied directly from the course?
2. I need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> *twice* after copying in that second block of code for it to run. Why is that?
3. Why does Atom insist on indenting the last `print` farther than my other indents?

Here is what I am seeing when entering my first code brick:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> while n > 0:
...     print(n)
...     n=n-1
... print('Blastoff!')
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print('Blastoff!')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you mixing spaces and tabs for indentation? That's my first instinct.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full error message (traceback) as properly formatted text. The common indentation used in Python is four spaces. Atom seems just to follow this convention.

Comment: @MichaelButscher n00b problems: I'm not sure what that all means. but if you explain it, I'd be happy to do it!

Comment: Just copy and paste the error message (which usually starts with "Traceback") in the question. Properly formatted means the code formatting here to ensure that the line breaks are preserved.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I didn't see the word "Traceback" anywhere, but I copied what is happening. Did I do the correct thing you were looking for? (Also, thank you for the help.)

Comment: @G.Anderson I was, yes, but I have now removed them and gone to just tabs, and nothing has changed. good catch, though, thank you!

Comment: Try typing each line from your original code into your own interpreter one by one. Sometimes when you copy and paste blocks like that, the indentation can get messed up.

Comment: @khuynh I tried that, but after I type the 'n=n-1' and hit enter, I don't get to type the rest, it just runs the code and gives the 54321 countdown.

Comment: Right, it'll execute the `while` block as soon as you finish it. This is because the interpreter executes the code line by line. Since you're writing the code in atom, you can try running the file from your terminal like so: `python myfile.py`. It'll execute all of the code in `myfile.py` (like you expect when you're copying and pasting).

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. The Python shell processes only one statement at once when pressing "return". You already placed the first line separately. The whole "while"-block is one statement but the following "print" is one of its own. You should place the code in a file and execute this file outside of the Python shell with a command line call like "python file.py"

Comment: @MichaelButscher ok, that answers another question I had, thank you! I have tried this, as khuyh also suggested, but when I type `python blastoff.py` I get `File "<stdin>", line 1
    python blastoff.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: The '^' points to the 'b' in 'blastoff', btw.

Comment: (And yes, my file is saved as blastoff.py in Atom)

Comment: No worries, this is because you're trying to run it _inside_ the python interpreter (you are using IDLE I assume?). If you're using IDLE, you can open `blastoff.py` using `File > Open` and then you can run the open file using `Run > Run Module`. This will signal the interpreter to run the entire file `blastoff.py`. Apologies if this isn't clear

Comment: @khuynh No, I am not in IDLE. (I never opened that and I have no clue what it is, to be honest. I'm *that* new). But I think python is looking for the file in the 'wrong' place. I'm searching for a solution to that now.

Comment: Are you running `python` in a windows command prompt? or a mac terminal?

Comment: @khuynh windows command prompt

Comment: Great. If you're already inside the python interpreter, you can write `quit()` to exit the interpreter and you'll be back inside the windows command prompt. If you've already exited the python interpreter, you can write `python blastoff.py` in the _windows command prompt_, and it will run your file. Let me know if it's not clear the distinction between the windows command prompt and the python interpreter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212445/discussion-between-the-count-and-khuynh).

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you for your help! we got it all sorted out in chat. i really appreciate your contribution, too!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". Don't apologize for not being experienced, just concentrate on creating a well-asked question.

Comment: Thanks, @theTinMan. Humility may be a virtue, but I appreciate that it seems lack of experience is not frowned upon. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're entering code into the Python interpreter, it'll interpret the code line-by-line. This is great for quick tests and checks, but for larger code, you'll want to run an entire file.

You can achieve this a couple different ways:

1. Running it from the command prompt/terminal. If your Python executable is in your PATH, you can open a command prompt and navigate to your file and run `python myfile.py`. See "[How to add Python to Windows PATH](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)".
2. If you've installed Python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/), you may have IDLE installed. You can run the IDLE application and open your file from the menu `File > Open`. From there, you can run the file from the menu `Run > Run Module`.

I'd suggest the second option since you are learning and it will help you focus on coding instead of fighting your code environment. However, feel free to revisit option #1 in the future. It is definitely helpful to know your way around the command line (if you work on a machine without IDLE installed, this would be the proper way to run Python files).

Also "[How to Run Your Python Scripts](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/)" is a great resource for learning more about how running scripts in Python works.

Comment: Thanks again for your help in chat, and for this helpful synopsis. I'm happy to report that both versions of my little goofy program are now running as expected.